# How to unserialize PHP sessions from Redis?

Tags: php, redis

How to unserialize PHP sessions stored in Redis? I need to fetch the session variables from a websocket server. Using `session_start()` is not possible

```
unserialize($this->redis->get('PHPREDIS_SESSION:'.$session_id));
```

Error

> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 319 bytes

Redis

`apt-get install php7.0-redis`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get PHPREDIS_SESSION:tmcls6v5n157q4kva4795hv4j1
"time_user_offset|i:0;activity_time|i:1535643086;ltype|s:6:\"CLIENT\";cid|i:1;uid|i:1;uid_admin|i:1;is_suspended|i:0;is_timeout_time|i:0;is_trial|i:0;is_full|i:1;lid|i:197240;is_ready|i:1;currency_name|s:3:\"DKK\";set_reverse_sign|i:0;bid|i:1;block_name|s:14:\"text\";addon_crm|i:1;suid|i:0;is_supporter|i:0;tmp|i:0;"
```

php.ini

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

## update

sessions work fine in PHP so it is not a bug

Comment: Didn't we do this question 30 minutes ago?

Comment: @RiggsFolly We did, but everyone in the comments (myself included) didn't read it properly (especially the edits)

Comment: as the man said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't use its standard serialization format for storing sessions. It's similar, but `unserialize` doesn't know how to read it. If you've configured Redis as a session store using the `session.save_handler` setting in php.ini, then it'll be using the default `serialize_handler` value, and storing your sessions using that serialization format.

Fortunately, you can still manually decode this in PHP - you just need to use [`session_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php) instead. This will populate the `$_SESSION` superglobal with the data you pass it (your string from Redis in this case), and you can then refer to it as you would in any other script.

Note that it you write back to the session on Server B, it won't be saved back to Redis (this is probably obvious, but just in case).

## Server A:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

## Server B:

```
<?php
session_start();

$data = $this->redis->get('...');
session_decode($data);

echo $_SESSION['foo']; // bar
```

Lastly, for clarity - this isn't an issue with Redis or the Redis session handler - you'd have the same issue if you were reading sessions from the filesystem and trying to use `unserialize` to decode them. The issue is just with the serialization format, rather than the storage.

Comment: your solution B gives `bool(true)`

Comment: ahh.. `$_SESSION` got the data :)

Comment: Yeah, `session_decode` is a bit annoying - it doesn't return the data, it just populates the session superglobal. But if that works for you then that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but I found the solution.

The problem with the default php session serializer called `php` is that it uses a format that is different to the serialization format the exposed [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions accepts. You experienced that.

But PHP has more built-in serializers than the `php` one. There is `php_serialize` which uses the format that is exposed via `serialize()` and `unserialize()`. (A quick search did not reveal since when.)

If you set [`session.serialize_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) `=  php_serialize` your code will work.

If you are dealing with a lot of data, I'd recommend using the [igbinary extension](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary). igbinary a proven serializer that uses a much more efficient binary format which you can unserialize as well.

```sh
$ pecl install igbinary
$ echo 'session.serialize_handler = igbinary' >> your/php.ini
```

```php
igbinary_unserialize($this->redis->get('PHPREDIS_SESSION:'.$session_id));
```

Comment: Very clear, thanks for an simple and effective explanation